# Error 1334. The file 'F23584_bcb.exe' cannot be installed

Tags: windows, c++builder

У меня при установке Borland C++ Builder 6 выдает ошибку:

> Error 1334. The file 'F23584_bcb.exe' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'bcb_exe.Cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Что мне делать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, у вас поломанный дистрибутив. Ищите другой. А зачем вам это старье? Очередной преподаватель в захолустном вузике задал? Передайте ему, что BC устарел 10 лет назад и содержит ошибки. Пора развиваться. Хотя бы в сторону Qt

Comment: Пфф, у нас "синенький" паскаль до сих пор преподавали бы, если бы я не сказал, что "всё, сломалось, юзайте паскаль абц".

Comment: И если ты окажешься прав на счёт шараги - то спешу тебя огорчить. Такие преподы просто так не сдаются. "Да и так всё же работает, зачем менять?" "Да я по этой методичке знаешь скока классных спецов выпустил? 20 лет, сносу нет" и моё любимое: "Да ничё принципиально нового не придумали, значит менять что-то в программе - нет смысла. Тем более министерство будет недевольно, а ещё мне за это не платят."